# CloudKit Asset Download failing over cellular data

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I'm using a public database in CloudKit for users to download assets, so in theory the user doesn't even need to log into iCloud.  I noticed a user getting Network Unavailable errors (CKError 4) almost instantly when attempting to download from LTE/4G.

Edit: Noticed this is happening over LTE/4G only when there is no iCloud account on the device.  However, this works on the same device without an iCloud account on Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

A user's iCloud storage won't affect their access to the public database.

This sounds like an issue with the user's cellular connection. Their service provider might be throttling them or there may be an issue with the cell towers in the area.

Comment: Thanks - I discovered a bit more and updated my original post